# DRF: error while updating a model with related user. Tries to created new related field

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model called `Content` for storing blogs etc. Each content is related to a user who created/modified it.
In my API view `put request`, I have a serializer error:

```
{'uid': {'email': [ErrorDetail(string='user with this email already exists.', code='unique')], 'name': [ErrorDetail(string='user with this name already exists.', code='unique')], 'password': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}}
```

The idea is to update the uid in case it is changed rather than creating a new user.

Content model:

```
class ContentType(models.TextChoices):
    BLOG = "blog"
    ARTICLE = "article"
    PRODUCT = "product"
    NAV = "nav"

    uid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=ContentType.choices, default=ContentType.BLOG)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    modifield = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    promote = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sticky = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ContentQueryset.as_manager()
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    postcode_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    customer_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "name"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My view:

```
class AdminView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if slug != "":
            try:
                content = Content.objects.get(slug=slug)
            except Content.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

            files = File.objects.filter(cid=content)
            contentAndAttachemnts = ContentAndAttachemnts(content=content, files=files)
            serializer = ContentAndAttachemntsSerializer(contentAndAttachemnts)

            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            contentList = Content.objects.all()
            serializer = ContentAdminSerializer(contentList, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        content = Content.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = ContentAdminUpdateSerializer(content, data=request.data["content"])
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Serializers:

```
class ContentAdminUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uid = UserUpdateSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Content
    fields = (
        "id",
        "title",
        "body",
        "type",
        "status",
        "uid",
        "created",
        "slug",
    )

class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id")
```

Postman PUT request json content body:

```
{
"content" : {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Some Title",
    "body": "<p><strong>Some Text</strong></p>",
    "type": "article",
    "status": true,
    "uid": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "created": "2015-07-24T06:08:58Z",
    "slug": "slug-123"
}}
```

Probably I would get user by given id, modify each field and then call save eg:

```
def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
    data = request.data
    content = Content.objects.get(pk=pk)
    title = data["content"]["title"]
    ...
    userId = data["content"]["uid"]["id"]
    user = User.objects.get(pk=userId)
    content.title = title
    content.uid = user
    content.save()
```

But the serializer approach looks much cleaner.

Comment: Is using just `"uid": 1` not an option?

Comment: "uid" object is serialized user data where id is the primary key but there are other fields like email or name. Nevertheless it don't see it solve my problem anyway. For now I am just using manual way without serializers and it is working...

Comment: Ah yes I mean in the `ContentAdminUpdateSerializer`, remove `uid = UserUpdateSerializer()` and just pass the `uid` foreign key, as the update does not need the nested representation of the user.